# While converting Png to Svg libssl not found. How to fix that?

Tags: python, openssl, aspose

Hello I am trying to convert Png images to Svg. At my windows computer I could convert png's with this code:

```
import aspose.words as aw

doc = aw.Document()
builder = aw.DocumentBuilder(doc)

shape = builder.insert_image("negative.png")
shape.image_data.save("Output.svg")
```

But now I'm in popOs and it gives this error:

```
No usable version of libssl was found
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tried updating openssl and installing libssl-dev.
Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: This doesn't convert to png. "Output.svg" is still a png file with a "svg" extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the code you are using does not convert PNG to SVG. `ImageData.Save` method saves the images in the original format, so the `Output.svg` file will be simply a PNG file with SVG extension.
If you need to wrap your PNG to SVG, you can use `ShapeRenderer`:

```py
doc = aw.Document()
builder = aw.DocumentBuilder(doc)

shape = builder.insert_image("C:\\Temp\\in.png")
shape.get_shape_renderer().save("C:\\Temp\\out.svg", aw.saving.ImageSaveOptions(aw.SaveFormat.SVG))
```

Also, please see [Linux system requirements of Aspose.Words for Python](https://docs.aspose.com/words/python-net/system-requirements/#system-requirements-for-target-linux-platform).
You should install `libsll` in your system. For example, here is Ubuntu docker configuration:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt update \
 && apt install -y python3.10 python3-pip libgdiplus wget \
 && wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb \
 && dpkg -i ./libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb \
 && rm -i libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb \
 && python3.10 -m pip install unittest-xml-reporting==3.2.0

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/python3.10"]
```

Comment: This just embeds the PNG into the SVG. From OP's deleted questions, they want the PNG vectorized.

Comment: This is a part of my project. For the final product i want a 3D model(.stl). I found some png to stl code but all the codes i found in python gives library issues are probably not from my pc. So i decided to take another look and first convert png's to svg and then svg to stl there is svg to stl codes too so I am trying to work out the first part of the project.

Comment: @gre_gor There is no way to vectorize PNG using Aspose.Words.

Comment: @han I have updated my answer. You should install `libssl` in your system

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate the effort. It solved the issue.

Comment: [libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.23_amd64.deb](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.23_amd64.deb)